# how to make iostat behave like top

Tags: perl, awk, sed, iostat

`iostat -xzN 5 | grep "^vg\|^Dev"` produces output like:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
vg01-root         0.00     0.00    0.00    0.20     0.00     1.60     8.00     0.00    3.00   3.00   0.06
vg05-vz           0.00     0.00    0.00    0.60     0.00     4.80     8.00     0.01    9.00   9.00   0.54
vg03-vz           0.00     0.00  281.00  128.40  5625.60  1027.20    16.25    42.35  103.54   2.44  99.94
vg02-vz2a         0.00     0.00   28.20   11.40  1416.00   112.00    38.59     0.79   19.84   5.99  23.72
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
vg05-vz           0.00     0.00    0.00    8.60     0.00  7876.80   915.91     0.48   55.70   3.40   2.92
vg03-vz           0.00     0.00  308.20   76.20 10376.00  4433.60    38.53    11.50   30.00   2.60 100.00
vg02-vz2a         0.00     0.00   27.80   24.80   604.80   198.40    15.27     0.49    9.39   4.89  25.72
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
vg05-vz           0.00     0.00    0.00    1.80     0.00   585.60   325.33     0.01    5.78   4.00   0.72
vg03-vz           0.00     0.00  323.20   49.00  9283.20   497.60    26.28     3.48    9.40   2.69  99.98
vg02-vz2a         0.00     0.00   40.20   55.80  2644.80   483.20    32.58     1.14   11.86   4.12  39.58
```

I'd like this to display like `top` i.e. clear screen and start from the top on each iteration.  I'm thinking if there was a way to pipe this through sed/awk/perl/whatever and every time you get `^Dev` push a `tput clear`.

But how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered [`iotop`](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) instead?

That said, it shouldn't be too hard to hurl some rough Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Adjust options to taste.
open(IOSTAT, "iostat -d 5 |") || die;

$| = 1;
while(<IOSTAT>) {
    if (/^Dev/) { system "clear"; print; }
    if (/^vg/) { print; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Was kinda looking for a one-liner but this will do.  I have iotop as well but have not found any way to monitor IO per disk device with that.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Jeffrey Hantin's response, here's a one-liner version:

```
S_COLORS=always iostat -hz 5 | perl -pe '/avg/ && system(q[clear])'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let watch do the work for you:

```
watch -n<interval> iostat`
```